# POST becomes GET on outgoing traffice

Tags: json, post, curl, get

I have a web instance on a Google Cloud virtual machine, built as UBUNTU

I am trying to POST data to an external API, but when I watch the traffic the POST is clearly becoming a GET.

I have checked the server .htaccess and site.conf file and can see no eveidence of rewrites or limiting

I have tried both PHP CURL and JQUery. Here are the IMPORTANT snippets of code from each attempt

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // I have also tried TRUE
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"\$xmldata=".urlencode($xmldata));
ob_start();
```

and the Jquery method (in full)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="application/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var example = {
            "Title": "REST DN transaction (JSON)",
            "Description": "REST DN transaction (JSON)",
            "TransactionType": 0,
            "Partner": {
                "PartnerId": xxxx },
            "Buyer": {
                "Email": "xxxx@hotmail.com", "Initiator": false,
                "CompanyChk": false,
                "AutoAgree": false, "AgreementChecked": false
            }, "Seller": {
                "Email": "xxxx@hotmail.com", "Initiator": true,
                "CompanyChk": false,
                "AutoAgree": false, "AgreementChecked": false
            }, "LineItems": [
                {
                    "ItemName": "test.com", "Description": "DN description", "Quantity": 1,
                    "Price": 2000,
                    "Accept": true,
                    "SellComm": 9.1,
                    "BuyComm": 10.1,
                }],
            "EPayment": 0, 
            "ShipmentFee": 0, 
            "ShipmentPayment":0, 
            "DomainNameType": 0, 
            "InspectionLength": 6, 
            "Currency": "USD", 
            "Fulfillment": 2, 
            "CommissionType": 1, 
            "InitiationDate": "2014-04-15", 
            "TermsLocked": true, 
            "AllowReject": true
        };

        $.post({
            type: "POST",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data :JSON.stringify(example),
            url: "https://thedomain.com/api/Transaction",
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have ALSO tried $.ajax(

Domain name is a placeholder

Can anyone advise why in google developer console when I watch the timeline the outgoing request is always a GET

The API is also returning a messging indicating GET is no=t allowed

Comment: Just to clarify, there is no error with the data being sent, I have just not added it to the snippet in both cases

Comment: if you don't show us more code, we can't tell you what the error is... curl doesn't just switch a POST to a GET for its own amusement!

Comment: You got that right!! but it IS!!

I will add the rest of the code

Comment: I have added the JQuery version IN full.. nothing missing, I run this script and watch console, it shows as a GET at every stage.., at no time is the method POST.. unless I am reading Google Dev console wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the code (no surprises) but the API. Thanks for those who took time to respond